# EventToCommandBehavior Namespace prefix 'b' is not defined

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to create an example from "Using the EventToCommandBehavior" (Prism Docs)
I'm getting a compilation error "Namespace prefix 'b' is not defined." and a red squiggly line bellow the "b" in the following line

```xml
<b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" />
```

The XAML Page is very simple as it is an example and look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="Intro.Views.Example03"
             x:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
  <StackLayout>
    <ListView.Behaviors>
      <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up. A PR has been submitted to correct this going forward. As suggested below 'x:b' should be 'xmlns:b' as you're creating an XML namespace alias.

Comment: @DanS. a PR to what ? this isn't the kind of error you can fix with patching the sources of XF (I haven't seen any) or Prism. Unless you mean a PR to fix a faulty documentation...

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix Yes a PR was submitted and merged to fix the faulty documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
x:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
```

should be

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a run time error when I'm visiting the View! The error is "Unfortunately, App1.Droid has stopped". The application works fine without the "<ListView.Behaviors>.. </ListView.Behaviors>" part

Comment: The reason that I'm getting a run time error is that the EventToCommandBehavior is not available yet in the version of prism that I'm using (6.2.0)